# How can I force text to appear underneath other layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

To emphasise one particular polygon area, I have used rule-based styles (QGIS) to apply a 50% transparency white fill to every polygon *but* the one I am interested in. This polygon layer is above all the others in the stack, with the result that all the mapping outside the emphasised polygon is 'faded out'.

However, any and all labels attached to places and roads are *not* faded out, even though the text layers in question are underneath the 'fade out' polygon layer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Eagerly awaiting the answer to this one. Very strange behavior! I'm able to duplicate this with any kind of overlay. In the meantime, there is an option to only label selected features, perhaps you can integrate that into your process?

Comment: Far too many features to select unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

You can not control the render order of labels. Labels are always rendered last and on top of everything else.

In the latest QGIS dev build you can set the label transparency, however labels will still not render on top as labels have collision detection.

If you still want to make the labels transparent you can set it in the label options:

[image]

If you only want to show the labels in the area of interest you could have a field in your points layer with the area name and use a label case statement to just show those labels:

```
CASE WHEN area = 'name' THEN "LabelColumn" END
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the labels _inside_ the fade out will be affected too.

Comment: Ahh I see what you want to do.  See my update

Comment: Where do I input the CASE statement?

Comment: In the label expression box.

Comment: Is that in the dev version only?

Comment: 1.8 has label expressions and `CASE`.  Click on the `...` button inside the label dialog.

Comment: I take it this will completely hide all labels outside the area though? I still want them visible, just faded out like the rest of mapping.

Comment: You can add the layer a second time and label the rest of the data with the inversed case statement faded.

Comment: Well, apparently my version of 1.8 (64 bit Ubuntu) doesn't have the expression option. No ... button anywhere in the label dialog. EDIT - my bad, I'm using the layer properties instead of labelling separately. Though the fact there are two different methods of doing it is ridiculous...

Comment: New problem - is there a way to efficiently (i.e. automatically) populate the points layer area name column? Because it's impossible (or at least highly impractical) to do it manually - we're talking over 59,000 points here.

Comment: `Though the fact there are two different methods of doing it is ridiculous..`  We are working on it don't worry.

Please ask a new question about the point in polygon problem

Answer (score 2):

Not straight forward, but possible:

You can clip all your data layers with the polygon using Vector->geoprocessing tools, and choose labelling only for that layer. For feature styling, choose a minimalistic design, or put it downmost in the stack.

A small example with OSM bus stops and admin borders:

[image]

Comment: I will try this

Comment: If you want faded labels as well, intersect a second time for the rest of the data.